# Symfony controller code

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I just started a project with Symfony and I think I am doing something wrong. Right now I want to a create simple page with table and filters so I created controller for it.

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index(Request $request) {
        //Form to add new documents
        $form = $this->newForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($this->getUser());
        //Gets all user documents
        $files = $user->getDocuments();
        //Gets all categories
        $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();

        //Adds new document to database
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $article = $form->getData();
            $article->setUser($this->getUser());
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($article);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }

        return $this->render('home/home.html.twig', [
            'files' => $files,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

This controller just displays documents in table and categories in navigaton. So then to add category filters I just made new function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{categoryId}")
 */
public function categories(request $request, $categoryId)
    {
        $form = $this->newForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($this->getUser());
        $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();

        $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Category::class)->findOneBy(["id" => $categoryId]);
        $categoryFiles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Document::class)->categoryFiles($category, $user);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $article = $form->getData();
            $article->setUser($this->getUser());
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($article);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }

        return $this->render('home/home.html.twig', [
            'files' => $categoryFiles,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Everything works, but I have to repeat same code for categories and forms in all of my functions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using S4?  Familiar at all with [services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)? You can reduce controller code by moving functionality into services and then inject the services into your controller.

Comment: I'm using Symfony 4. Yeah I am familiar with services, but wasn't sure if I should use it here. So now I just need to make services for all code I reuse and import it. Thanks.

Comment: Yep.  Take it a bit at a time.  Maybe make yourself a CategoryFinder as a starting point just to get familiar with the mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use **services**, a Service can be (Business Rules, Helpers, MicroServices, etc.), the most import is the **Business Rules**, generally should exists a service by entity

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$info = $this->get(HomeService::class)->getInfo($user, null);
// TODO FORM

return $this->render('home/home.html.twig', [
    'files' => $info['files'],
    'categories' => $info['categories'],
    'form' => $form->createView()
```

]);

Second Action

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$info = $this->get(HomeService::class)->getInfo($user, $categoryId);
// TODO FORM

return $this->render('home/home.html.twig', [
    'files' => $info['category_files'],
    'categories' => $info['categories'],
    'form' => $form->createView()
```

]);

HomeService->info(), it will process all

[Symfony Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i5ou.png)

Answer (score -1):

Create abstract class, then extend from child controllers. You can read also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

It's **just** one way, **can be** more ways!

Comment: What's the connection to late static bindings? And no, logic to that extend should never be in a controller, that's none of the usual ways

Comment: How i said, it's just one way, can be create new service then usage example: $this->container->get("new_service")->getCategoryList();

Comment: And what is the connection to late static bindings? Why did you link that page?

Comment: i went to more help to him for understanding abstract methods, he need call some methods from many controllers, then some variables can be declared in child classes.